# Sequence within SQL Select

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having a bit of a problem with using my sequence within a `SELECT` statement.

```
SELECT
     c.cust_name,
     c.site,
     customer_id_seq.nextval    
FROM
     customer c
WHERE
     c.customer_id IS NULL
ORDER BY
     c.site_code ASC
;
```

Is giving me an error:

> 2287. 00000 -  "sequence number not allowed here"
>         *Cause:    The specified sequence number (CURRVAL or NEXTVAL) is
>         inappropriate
>                here in the statement.
>         *Action:   Remove the sequence number.

It's probably something obvious I'm doing wrong so hopefully this will be an easy answer.

Comment: This looks like Oracle.  Is that right?  Might want to add a tag.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot use sequences in queries with `ORDER BY`.

Remove the `ORDER BY` or put in into a subquery:

```
SELECT  q.*, customer_id_seq.nextval    
FROM    (
        SELECT  c.cust_name,
                c.site
        FROM    customer c
        WHERE   c.customer_id IS NULL
        ORDER BY
                c.site_code ASC
        ) q
```

Comment: This is correct and one of the limitations. If you want to pull sequences for the records in a particular order move the query (with order by) into an inline view and select the contents + the sequence from that

Comment: Thanks for the help on this guys, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

for [IBM Imformix](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/sqls1016.htm)

In a SELECT statement, you cannot specify NEXTVAL or CURRVAL in the following contexts:

- In the projection list when the DISTINCT keyword is used
- **In the WHERE, GROUP BY, or ORDER BY clauses**
- In a subquery
- When the UNION operator combines SELECT statements

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use rownum instead of fetching values from sequence?

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering why he was using a sequence here. Doesn't seem appropriate...

Comment: Most of the customers in the database already have ID's so I need to continue from that number onwards. I'm inserting these results into another table. 

Thanks again.