# generate sequence when inserting results from other table result set Oracle

Tags: oracle, for-loop, sequence

I have a resultset of a select statement from a table 'test_inter'.
I use this to insert entries in other table which has id(incremented by sequence), while inserting in loop from resultset , i am getting error

```
 --Edit starts

        BEGIN

            l_sql := 'select null as rid,null as  rtype, null as sid,null as cid, null as  pid,mid ,name, origin ,ctry, instyle,null as mapct,null as defspct,null as addspct,null as opct ';


            FOR i IN 1 .. n_vers
            LOOP
                l_sql := l_sql || ', max( case when verorder = ' || i || ' then hoing else 0 end ) as h' || i;
                l_sql := l_sql || ', max( case when verorder = ' || i || ' then hoingpct else 0 end ) as p' || i;
            END LOOP;
            FOR i IN n_vers + 1 .. max_vers
            LOOP
                l_sql := l_sql || ', max( case when verorder = ' || i || ' then hoing else null end ) as h' || i;
                l_sql := l_sql || ', max( case when verorder = ' || i || ' then hoingpct else null end ) as p' || i;
            END LOOP;
            l_sql := l_sql || ', rowgroup,  sid,null as sname, null as hoingorder, null as plead, null as cneutral, null as notnullcol,null as notnullcolindex, null as SECPCT from
        (select mid ,name, origin ,ctry, instyle ,cid, cverid,  verorder, hoingpct, hoing,rowgroup,sid
        from test_inter
        where  rid = ' || n_rid || ' and sid = ''' || c_sid || '''  and rtype = ' || n_rtype || ' and pid = ' || n_pid || ' order by verorder  ) group by  mid ,name, origin ,ctry, instyle,rowgroup,sid ';

--n _vars and max_vars are constant values
           -- Edit Ends


            EXECUTE immediate l_sql;   -- gives me result set
                OPEN rc FOR l_sql;
                LOOP
                    FETCH rc INTO cp_row;
                    IF rc%FOUND THEN
                        INSERT
                        INTO test_final
                            (   
                                id     ,  --: ORA-01007: variable not in select list"
                                rid    ,
                                rtype  , 
                             -- more fields
                            )VALUES
                            (  seq.nextval,
                               cp_row.rid,
                               cp_row.rtype,
                               -- more values);
                    ELSE
                        EXIT;
                    END IF;
                    --exit when rc%NOTFOUND;
                END LOOP;
                CLOSE rc;   

        END;
```

I am getting error"Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01007: variable not in select list", while I am trying to generate id and insert it.
I need to insert sequence also , when inserting any row in table test_final, how could i do it?Any leads on this will be helpful.

Edit 2

My issue is almost similar to this question

[Sequence within SQL Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245125/sequence-within-sql-select)

Where i want to have sequence generated for table "test_final", but i am not able to use nextval.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you use dynamic SQL? What is `l_sql`, exactly? Can you not use it directly in a cursor FOR loop and do what you are doing? Or, even better, avoid loop and/or PL/SQL completely and do everything using a single INSERT statement at the SQL level?

Comment: I did not want to confuse , so have not added how select statement is building from l_sql. I have edited question and added that part. 'select' statement is not straight forward so i think single insert statement is not possible here. Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: Regarding the sequence, assuming you are on 12.1 or later, it might be simpler just to give the table an [identity column](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1) and forget about it.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle hurls `ORA-01007` when the projection of a SELECT statement contains a different number of columns to the target.

In your case there are **two** places which might raise this exception:

- the projection of the dynamic SQL statement doesn't match the declaration of the record type of `cp_row`
- the list of columns in your `insert into test_final (...)` does not match the list of columns in your `select ...`.

You have indicated the INSERT statement as the line which fails but the two statements are next to each other, and dynamic SQL is a lot harder to get right. In fact the more I look at your code the more likely it seems that the dynamic SQL is the problem.

Your code does this:

```
FOR i IN 1 .. n_vers
LOOP
    l_sql := l_sql || ', max( case when verorder = ' || i || ' then hoing else 0 end ) as h' || i;
    l_sql := l_sql || ', max( case when verorder = ' || i || ' then hoingpct else 0 end ) as p' || i;
END LOOP;
FOR i IN n_vers + 1 .. max_vers
LOOP
    l_sql := l_sql || ', max( case when verorder = ' || i || ' then hoing else null end ) as h' || i;
    l_sql := l_sql || ', max( case when verorder = ' || i || ' then hoingpct else null end ) as p' || i;
END LOOP;
```

Which means the final number of columns in the dynamic SELECT will vary depending on the value of `max_vers`. How does the project of the RECORD TYPE handle this variability?

---

> [me]: `seq.nextval` maps to `id` does it not?
>   [op]: yes , in test_final table.But select statment does not have any id

Fnord. It has the `seq.nextval` instead. I have been using `insert into whatever select seq.nextval,` constructs for over twenty-five years. That is not the problem. The problem is the projection of the SELECT clause doesn't match the destination projection.

But not the projections of the INSERT statement. If the problem was the INSERT statement Oracle would have hurled `ORA-00947: not enough values` or `ORA-00913: too many values` (depending on which projection was the unbalanced one).

The problem is **the fetch of the generated SELECT into the `cp_row` variable**.

Here is an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2cce9f/1) demonstrating that your dynamic SQL statement is the problem. The first run succeeds because the projection of the SELECT statement matches the declaration of the RECORD type. The second run fails because the SELECT statement has a different projection.

We get the `ORA-01007` error because it's dynamic SQL. Static SQL would have produced the irrefutable

> ORA-06504: PL/SQL: Return types of Result Set variables or query do not match

Dynamic SQL is hard because it turns compilation errors into runtime errors, and it's really hard to debug. What you need to do is display the `l_sql` variable before (or instead of) executing it. Then you can compare the generated projection to the declaration of the record type and find teh inconsistency.

Comment: Yes , i know this is exactly the case.I want to inset sequence(primary key ) in test_final which is not present in the select statement.

Comment: I wanted to know, how cud i do it. From error statement " ORA-01007: variable not in select list", it made me clear that there is mismatch in select and insert parameters. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In 'insert' statement, this seq.nextval is causing issue. I need to insert next sequence as primary key in test_final table.

Comment: `seq.nextval` maps to `id` does it not?

Comment: yes , in test_final table.But select statment does not have any id

Comment: I have written a test case on SQL Fiddle which strongly suggests the problem is the dynamic SQL statement not the insert statement. Please run it and check your code.

Answer (score 0):

Aha. So, `l_sql` is a *large* `SELECT` statement. I don't know how it looks like when it is finally composed, but - I presume you checked that it runs OK. If that's so, here's an idea:

- create a (global temporary) table (let's call it `gtt_sql`) which contains all columns that `l_sql` query returns
- instead of just *selecting*, use `l_sql` as a source for `insert into gtt_sql` (you'd use `execute immediate`)
- once you have data in the table, rewrite your current code, e.g.

---

```
-- this substitutes everything you put between `OPEN` and `CLOSE` cursor commands
for cur_r in (select column_list from gtt_sql) loop
  insert into test_final ...
end loop;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. Is there any way , other than creating another temporary table? Otherwise, i will have to try this. Thanks.

Comment: You could use a collection, but - from my point of view, a GTT is simpler.

Comment: I don't see why a GTT would make this problem disappear. The issue is that SELECT projection doesn't match the INSERT projection. What difference would it make to select from a GTT rather than record variable ?

Comment: It won't disappear, but it might help to see easier what's going on. When data is in a table, you can select from it and in a matter of seconds see what you have. With a record variable, it is a tedious job (as it seems that the OP didn't post *everything* they have, according to "more values" note). I just thought that such a *complex* `l_sql` is difficult to follow. Besides, if it really was a GTT, then there's no need to *loop* through it - a simple `INSERT INTO test final SELECT FROM gtt` would do it.

Comment: The problem is the fetch of the dynamic SQL into the variable, not the insert at all. Here is [a SQL Fiddle which reproduces the error](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2cce9f/2).

Comment: Apparently, yes. Thank you for a nice example, @APC. Shortly, I missed the point. Will remove this answer (in a few minutes, so that you'd read this comment), it doesn't help at all.

Comment: Hi , i was having this sql code (select from other table , get a result set and insert using for loop) already which was all working. Here , test_final table is holding temporary data and did not have any primary key column. so in bigger picture, my requirement was to add a sequence to each insert statement for test_final. Only for the above situation , i am getting issue entering a sequence number as it uses resultset from other table.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; don't you - if you use this approach - just `insert into test_final (id, bla, bla1) select seq.nextval, bla, bla1 from gtt`? How could that fail?

Comment: yes, finally i have used this approach. Used nextval in 'select' statement. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As a next step of mismatch between select (resultset) and insert statements (sequence for insertion) , i tried to use nextval with 'select' statement.
But as 'Select' was having group by clause so I was not able to put nextval on 'select' statement.

I have got this working with below code:
l_sql := 'SELECT  q.*, sh_rpt_temp_peer_final_seq.nextval as id FROM  (' || l_sql || ') q';

I am accepting answer on this post:

[Sequence within SQL Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245125/sequence-within-sql-select)

Thank you.

Comment: So all the code you posted in your question had nothing to do with the ORA-01007 you complained about? That's an hour of my life I won't get back.

Comment: @APC, As i posted in my question that 1) I was getting this error initially when i was using in  seq.nextval in Insert statement but this field was not there in select statement.(mismatch) 2) Then I added  seq.nextval in select statement as shown in my answer , then it solved my answer. I am upvoting your's and Littlefoot's comment which helped me to think through the process. Thanks a lot APC. Really appreciate your response.